# Comparar varios elementos de una matriz

Tags: java, array, string

Quisiera saber si podrian ayudarme con este problemilla que tengo.

Estoy haciendo una variacion basica del juego tetris en consola como parte de una tarea, soy bastante novato en Java, recien empiezo y me he quedado atrapado en el sistema de punteo/eliminacion de coincidencias.

Tengo una matriz llena de espacios (tablero de juego) que se va llenando con las figuras del tetris, entonces, en cierto momento del juego tengo:

[image: Ejemplo]

Como podeis ver, tengo 4 elementos similares, que deberían haberse eliminado, La unica solucion que se me ocurre es de recorrer toda la matriz y revisar si en x columna existen 4 caracteres iguales, eliminarlos y sumar puntos... de esta manera:

```
for (int y=1;y<Tablero.length-1;y++){

            for(int x=1;x<Tablero[y].length-4;x++){
                if(Tablero[y][x].equals(Tablero[y][x+1])&&Tablero[y][x+1].equals(Tablero[y][x+2])&&Tablero[y][x].equals(Tablero[y][x+3])&&Tablero[y][x]!=" "){
                    puntos=puntos+1;
                    Tablero[y][x]=" ";
                    Tablero[y][x+1]=" ";
                    Tablero[y][x+2]=" ";
                    Tablero[y][x+3]=" ";
                }
            }
```

Pero esta solucion ademas de ser bastante fea, solo vale para el caso especifico de 4 iguales, si hay mas de 4 no las toma en cuenta.

Asi que en si, la pregunta seria:  ¿Como puedo recorrer una matriz y comprobar si 4 o mas elementos son iguales?

De antemano gracias por cualquier sugerencia

Comment: Solo debes comprobar que existan 4 o mas iguales en horizontal? O en vertical tambien como en el tetris original?

Comment: Si, en vertical tambien, pero supongo que resolviendo el problema que del horizontal facilmente puedo deducir la solucion para vertical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomando el codigo que poner y esta pregunta:

*Asi que en si, la pregunta seria: ¿Como puedo recorrer una matriz y comprobar si 4 o mas elementos son iguales?*

ya esta comprobando los cuatro ahora solo seguir.

```
for (int y=1;y<Tablero.length-1;y++){

            for(int x=1;x<Tablero[y].length-4;x++){ // podria ser que fuera Tablero[x]?

                if(Tablero[y][x].equals(Tablero[y][x+1]) &&
                   Tablero[y][x+1].equals(Tablero[y][x+2]) &&
                   Tablero[y][x].equals(Tablero[y][x+3]) &&
                   Tablero[y][x]!=" "){

                    puntos=puntos+1;

                    Tablero[y][x]=" ";
                    Tablero[y][x+1]=" ";
                    Tablero[y][x+2]=" ";
                    Tablero[y][x+3]=" ";

                    // 18 creo mide su pantalla a ojo de buen cubero
                    // 18 - 4 ajustar esto

                    for (int a = 1; a < (18 - 4); a++){

                        if(Tablero[y][x+3 + a] != null){ /*este null para que no 
                                                         este fuera del array 
                                                         en cuanto exista un null esta fuera de la pantalla asi que puede poner un else, para que deje de mirar en el for. algo asi como else{ a = 20;*/

                            if(Tablero[y][x].equals(Tablero[y][x+3 + a]){

                                Tablero[y][x+3 + a] = " ";
                                //no se si se tendria que sumar mas puntos por cada uno de mas, de ser asi podria hacerlo aqui

                            }else{


                            //en el momento que deja de ser igual salimos
                            a = 20;
                            }

                        }else{

                            //salimos
                            a = 20;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Esto es una idea, no he podido probarlo, pero creo que es muy probable que le funcione.

Comment: Es que me he hecho un lio con lo de las X & Y y al final las posiciones me han quedado (y,x) por eso es que he realizado el recorrido de la matriz de esa forma! (y = filas, x=columnas), pero gracias! me has ayudado bastante compañero!